# "git submodule" comes back empty

Tags: git

i use the following sequence to initialize and update git submodules:

```
git init
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Then I want to see all the submodules, by this command:

```
git submodule
```

It prints out nothing unfortunately.

My .gitmodules file is in the same directory and contains known to be working submodule definitions.

Please note that I called `git init` as the very first command. If I didn't do that, `git submodule init` would complain that there is no valid git repository.

Why would `git submodule` not print anything?

Comment: Because [git-submodule](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) without any parameters is not a valid command.

Comment: @user1615903 That's what I thought at first, but it runs in repos I have. `git --version`: 1.7.12.4. @thumbmunkeys: are you running a recent-ish version of git?

Comment: git version prints 1.8.1.msysgit.1

Comment: @user1615903: it think it is a valid command, according to this at least: http://renprovey.com/git/2010/07/12/git-submodule/

Comment: could the problem be, that I called `git init` as the very first command?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I think that, unless you've done `git clone` or `git submodule add`, you've not actually added any submodules. The presence of a `.gitmodules` isn't enough - check in `.git/config` to see if there are any lines that look like `[submodule foo]`. If there's not, you dont have any submodules in your repo, so `git submodule` is working as it should.

Comment: @simont: thanks! i figured that, post this as answer I will mark it then

Comment: I had a similar problem when I cloned using http, but the submodules were registered using ssh, and ssh was blocked by the company firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

Unless you've done `git clone` or `git submodule add`, you've not actually added any submodules. The presence of a `.gitmodules` isn't enough - check in `.git/config` to see if there are any lines that look like `[submodule foo]`. If there's not, you dont have any submodules in your repo, so `git submodule` is working as it should.